# Missing glyph in Google Webfont Radley italic?

Tags: css, google-webfonts

I've started designing a project using the Radley typeface from Google Webfont (https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Radley).

I've noticed that the character sequence "st" in italic shows as blank **in Windows 7 at least**. I wonder if there may be a glyph missing? "s" and "t" italic exist individually but it looks like the font uses ligatured variants for certain sequences.

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/nltesown/pen/tpfoy (the second line outputs: Ea is We)

```
<p>East is West</p>
<p><em>East is West</em></p>
<p><em>Eas t is Wes t</em></p>
```

Using `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Radley:400,400italic`

**EDIT :** it seems to be a Firefox (32?) issue. Works normally in Chrome or IE.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it with:

```
font-style: italic;
text-rendering: initial;
letter-spacing: 0.0003em;
```

Unfortunately there are some old browsers where this is not working.

---

Edit: You can try add also this lines.

```
-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
```

Comment: I found out you can also use
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
    font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;

The combination with above should be 100% fix for Radley font.

Comment: -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=0"; /* Firefox 4-14 */

Comment: great answer! amazing

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I used the answer above but found it did not resolve when testing on iphone 5. Answer: put a comment in between the 's' and 't'.

```
eg: "s<!-- fix -->t"
```

Worked a treat :)